# Insertion Sort of an array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

For one of my assignments I have to have a user input a list of names and while they are inputting them, they have to be sorted alphabetically as they go. I was wondering (1) when declaring an array of strings which is best to use:

```
char test[10][10];
```

or

```
char *test[10];
```

and (2) the best way to write an insertion method, I know how to write an insertion sort method and there are many examples online on it but they deal mainly with just 1D arrays, so I'm a little lost on how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "declare"? Both those declarations you show are, on their own, invalid. Except the second which is valid as the last member of a structure, but only there. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I know in C, strings are just char arrays, so when declaring (in a general context) an array of strings, which way is the most ideal way, maybe don't be a d*ckhead next time to someone who's trying to learn

Comment: Didn't we use to have a [tag:homework] tag?

Answer (score 2):

The declarations you show are *very* different. The first is an array of arrays of `char`, and the second is an array of pointers to `char` (also known as a *jagged array*).

Both could be treated similarly, like arrays of strings, but there are quite a few semantic differences. For example, in the first your strings are limited to nine character (plus terminator) while in the second the strings could be of any length (fitting in memory).

There's also a difference in how the two arrays *decays* (what happens when you use plain `test` when a pointer is expected). The first will decay to a pointer to an array of `char`, i.e. `char (*)[10]`. The second will decay to pointer to pointer to `char`, i.e. `char **`.

Now for the big question: Which should you use? Well that really depends on use-case. Will you have only fixed-sized strings where the size is known from the start (and the total size is small enough to fit on the stack where local variables normally are stored)? Then you can use the first. If you don't know the length of the strings, or if they could differ by more than a few characters, then the second is probably a better choice.

---

The second question depends a lot on the choice of arrays. If you have arrays of arrays (the first declaration) then you need to copy strings around using `strcpy`. If you chose array of pointers (the second declaration) you could just assign the pointers around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to solve assignments here, so I'll just give a brief push into the right direction:

What you want is a linked list; then, whenever the user enters a new name, you can insert the new entry directly into it at the correct position.

A first start could look like this:

```
struct entry { char name[10]; struct entry* next; };

struct entry* root = NULL;

void addname(char* na) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (struct entry*)malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
        sprintf(entry->name, "%s", na);
    }else{
        // HERE, walk through all entries! Once you reach one, where next is lex. greater then you create a new entry, and link it into that position of the chain
    }
}
```